# Android WebView with token cannot access to the account

Tags: android, webview, token, android-sharedpreferences

I'm try to access on my website through WebView, but before show to my users the WebView they must enter username and password and after that they could be able to see their account dashboard into WebView.
The issue is that actually I could keep my auth_token and store it into SharedPreferences but after how I can say to my webview that this user have already done the login and has already the auth_token?
I would allow my user to use the website while he is on my android app.
This is the code:
    public class Login_Page extends Activity{
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

```
String token="";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);
    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);}

public void LaunchWebView(View view) {
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String token2= mPreferences.getString("auth_token","");

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String sessionCookie = "staging=" + token;
    map.put("auth_token",token2);

    myWebView.loadUrl("url", map);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue and I rewrite the code, here what I modified:

```
public class Login_Page extends Activity{
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

String token="";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);
    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void LaunchWebView(View view) {

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView, true);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String token2= mPreferences.getString("auth_token","");

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("x-auth-token", token2);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.photospotland.com/spots/where", map);
}
}
```

I hope this can help someone.
Thanks.

Comment: setAcceptThirdPartyCookies methos is supporting min 21 api level